# Calculate the anniversary date for each row and for each index

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

the first row of my contract **144** starts at **2008-02-11** and ends at **2011-03-28**. I want to calculate the **anniversary date** for each year between **2008** and **2011** (For 144 and others contracts)

the main goal is to check for each row of contract if the anniversary date its ok, if its not calculate it and update the start and the end with the right values

*this is my pandas dataframe which concerns two contracts **"144"** and **"150"**:

| index | NUM_contrat | start | end | anniversary | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 144 | 2008-02-11 | 2011-03-28 | 2009-02-11 | 550 |
| 1 | 144 | 2011-03-28 | 2011-09-19 | 2012-02-11 | 550 |
| 2 | 150 | 2011-09-19 | 2012-02-10 | 2012-09-19 | 900 |
| 3 | 150 | 2012-02-10 | 2013-02-10 | 2013-09-19 | 900 |

*this is the dataframe i want to get :

| index | NUM_contrat | start | end | anniversary | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 144 | 2008-02-11 | 2009-02-11 | 2009-02-11 | 550 |
| 0 | 144 | 2009-02-11 | 2010-02-11 | 2010-02-11 | 550 |
| 0 | 144 | 2010-02-11 | 2011-02-11 | 2011-02-11 | 550 |
| 0 | 144 | 2011-02-11 | 2011-03-28 | 2012-02-11 | 550 |
| 1 | 144 | 2011-03-28 | 2011-09-19 | 2012-02-11 | 550 |
| 2 | 150 | 2011-09-19 | 2012-02-10 | 2012-09-19 | 900 |
| 3 | 150 | 2012-03-28 | 2012-07-11 | 2013-09-19 | 900 |

***this is my code that works only when i have only one Num_contract but doesnot work with 2 or more NUM_Contrat***

```
    
for NUM_contrat in df['NUM_contrat'].unique():

    for i in df['index'].unique():

       for index,row in df.iterrows():

           if df.iloc[index]['end'] > df.iloc[index]['anniversary']:

               df1=pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[index]).transpose() 

               df.loc[index, 'end'] = df.loc[index, 'anniversary']

               df= pd.concat([df,df1],ignore_index=True).sort_values(['start','end']).reset_index(drop=True)

               df.loc[index+1,'start'] = df.loc[index,'anniversary']
               df.loc[index+1,'anniversary'] = df.loc[index,'anniversary'] + relativedelta(years=1)
                    
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** according to your comment to have more than one row for each contract.

The following snippet could answer to your problem.

```
>>> data
   NUM_contrat      start        end anniversary  quantity
0          144 2008-02-11 2011-03-28  2009-02-11       550
1          144 2011-03-28 2011-09-19  2012-02-11       550
2          150 2011-09-19 2012-02-10  2012-09-19       900
3          150 2012-02-10 2013-02-10  2013-09-19       900
```

```
for _, sr in data.loc[data["anniversary"] < data["end"]].iterrows():
    df = sr.to_frame().transpose()
    periods = sr["end"].year - sr["start"].year
    idx = pd.date_range(sr["anniversary"], periods=periods, freq="Y")
    idx += pd.DateOffset(days=sr["anniversary"].day, months=sr["anniversary"].month - 1)
    data = pd.concat([data, df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(idx))].assign(anniversary=idx)])
```

```
  NUM_contrat      start        end anniversary quantity
0         144 2008-02-11 2011-03-28  2009-02-11      550
0         144 2008-02-11 2011-03-28  2010-02-11      550
0         144 2008-02-11 2011-03-28  2011-02-11      550
0         144 2008-02-11 2011-03-28  2012-02-11      550
1         144 2011-03-28 2011-09-19  2012-02-11      550
2         150 2011-09-19 2012-02-10  2012-09-19      900
3         150 2012-02-10 2013-02-10  2013-09-19      900
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help :) but this is doent work if i have more than one row for each contract. The mean idea is to check for each contract, each row : is the anniversary its ok, do nothing if its note split and calculate ! i updated the dataframe if you can see.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

- generate a date range for **start** date
- `explode()` it to generate required rows
- calc **end** and **anniversary**

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""index   NUM_contrat start   end anniversary quantity
0   144 2008-02-11  2011-03-28  2009-02-11  550
1   144 2011-03-28  2011-09-19  2012-02-11  550
2   150 2011-09-19  2012-02-10  2012-09-19  900
3   150 2012-02-10  2013-02-10  2013-09-19  900"""), sep="\t", index_col=0)

# cleanup - make sure dates are dates
df.start = pd.to_datetime(df.start)
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df.end)
df.anniversary = pd.to_datetime(df.anniversary)
df
# # generate a date range for start, based on end date
df2 = (df.assign(start=df.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(r.start, 
                                                 periods=((r.end.year+1)-r.start.year), 
                                                 freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1)), axis=1))
# explode the start dates
 .explode("start")
# calc end and anivversary dates
 .assign(end=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.start.dt.year==dfa.end.dt.year,dfa.end, dfa.start+pd.DateOffset(years=1)),
        anniversary=lambda dfa: dfa.start+pd.DateOffset(years=1))
# anniversary is always the one from the first instance of the contract
 .assign(anniversary=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby(["NUM_contrat",dfa.start.dt.year])["anniversary"].transform("first"))
)

df2
```

#### output

| index | NUM_contrat | start | end | anniversary | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 144 | 2008-02-11 00:00:00 | 2009-02-11 00:00:00 | 2009-02-11 00:00:00 | 550 |
| 0 | 144 | 2009-02-11 00:00:00 | 2010-02-11 00:00:00 | 2010-02-11 00:00:00 | 550 |
| 0 | 144 | 2010-02-11 00:00:00 | 2011-02-11 00:00:00 | 2011-02-11 00:00:00 | 550 |
| 0 | 144 | 2011-02-11 00:00:00 | 2011-03-28 00:00:00 | 2012-02-11 00:00:00 | 550 |
| 1 | 144 | 2011-03-28 00:00:00 | 2011-09-19 00:00:00 | 2012-02-11 00:00:00 | 550 |
| 2 | 150 | 2011-09-19 00:00:00 | 2012-09-19 00:00:00 | 2012-09-19 00:00:00 | 900 |
| 2 | 150 | 2012-09-19 00:00:00 | 2012-02-10 00:00:00 | 2013-09-19 00:00:00 | 900 |
| 3 | 150 | 2012-02-10 00:00:00 | 2013-02-10 00:00:00 | 2013-09-19 00:00:00 | 900 |
| 3 | 150 | 2013-02-10 00:00:00 | 2013-02-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-10 00:00:00 | 900 |

Comment: thank you so much , this partially works .my data could contains for exemple another row for contract 144 that start from 28-03-2011 to 19-09-2011 and i want the anniversary for this row to be on 11-02-2011 (The anniversary for each contract should be at the same date). i updated the dataframe if you can help :)

Comment: that's a simple addition to the logic,  one line of code added to further specify **anniversary**